# Random inputs and loops in python

Tags: python

```
from random import randint as r

x = r(1, 100)
y = r(1, 10)

def rannum(x,y):

if (x==y):
    m = 2*y
else:
    z = x * y
    print z  
rannum(x,y)
```

I have value of x and y which are randomly generated and I have a function which has two condition. How could I construct loop to meet my x==y condition? How could I know home many times I ran the loop to meet this condition. I am fairly new to programming and got stuck to this point. Please suggest/recommend me the way to achieve the result. I have made the range of  smaller so that there could be high probability of selecting same number.Thankyou

Comment: What do you mean? Should `rannum` modify the values of `x` and `y` *until* they are equal?

Comment: what are m and z values?

Comment: If this is for testing, just pick one random number and pass it as both arguments: `x = r(1,100); rannum(x, x)`.

Comment: no. I added rannum to run the function only.

Comment: m and z are just variable to store smth. I used it for illustration purpose only. I am intrested in looping inside rannum function to see when could be the value of x == y. I mean in how many attempts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are doing it, but below is what I understand from your question.

```
from random import randint as r
def rannum(x,y):
  if (x==y):
    m = 2*y
    print m
  else:
    z = x * y
    print z  

count=0
while True:
  count=count+1
  x = r(1, 100)
  y = r(1, 10)
  if (x==y):
    print "x is equal to y after count=",count
    rannum(x,y)
    break
```

Comment: what is use of m there and z?

Comment: `m` and `z` are not required actually,they are just storing the product of x and y before printing them.

Comment: y just print you can remove though user used it. there is no use of m and z i think

Comment: yes , it is not necessary to use them , i copied this function from the question.

Comment: In this case yeah there is no use of m and z. I used it because I need to use the value later on.

Comment: instead of 1 give true